# ¿Cómo puedo ir de una página a otra en Spring Boot Netbeans, me sale Whitelabel Error Page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Cuando corro la página me sale normal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero luego cuando quiero ir a "Control de tienda" que es otro HTML llamado "nuevo.html" que se encuentra en mi paquete de templates, sale error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controlador

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;@ComponentScan(basePackages=("pe.edu.ucs.jpa2022.controller"))
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "indexnuevo";
      
    }
}
```

otro controlador, esta es para realizar las operaciones con la base de datos

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cliente")
public class ClienteRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Cliente> getPosts() {
        return clienteService.readAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cliente> getPost(@PathVariable int id) {
        Cliente cliente = clienteService.read(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(cliente);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deletePost(@PathVariable int id) {        
        clienteService.delete(id);
    }
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Cliente addPost(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {  
        return clienteService.create(cliente);
    }
    @PutMapping("/edit")
    public Cliente editPost(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {  
        Cliente pos = new Cliente(cliente.getIdcliente(),cliente.getNombre(),cliente.getTelefono(),cliente.getDireccion());
        System.out.println(cliente.getIdcliente()+" , "+cliente.getNombre()+" , "+cliente.getTelefono()+" , "+cliente.getDireccion());
        return clienteService.update(cliente);
    }
    
    

}
```

Mi html: aqui pongo "nuevo.html" pero parece que no lo lee,

```
<html lang="es" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>spring</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
        <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.css} "/>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="nuevo.html">Control de tienda</a>
            
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                     
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="nuevo.html" th:src="@{/js/script.js/nuevo.html}">Agregar Producto</a>
                        </li>
           
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div class="container text-center">
            <br>
            <h3>Lista de Clientes</h3>
            <hr>
            <button class="btn btn-danger mb-5"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGuardar" data-whatever="@mdo">Add</button>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tablita">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">NOMBRES</th>
                                <th scope="col">TELEFONO</th>
                                <th scope="col">DIRECCION</th>
                                <th scope="col" colspan="2">ACCIÓN</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Guardar Post -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalGuardar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nuevo Empleado</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nombre:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Apellido:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">DNI:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="dni" placeholder="DNI"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar">Registrar Empleado</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Modificar Post -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalEditar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modificar Empleado</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nombre:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editar_nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="idempleado" value="0">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Apellido:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="editar_apellido" placeholder="Apellido"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">DNI:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="editar_dni" placeholder="DNI"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modificar">Modificar Empleado</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.5.2/bootbox.min.js"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/script.js}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

....ASI ES SU ESTRUCTURA, he probado muchas opciones incluso la de @ComponentScan() pero hace que mi pagina desaparezca, como arriba me sale error 404, tambien he intentado poner otros paquetes y demás pero parece que no funciona al momento de correr la página
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Probaste cambiando `href="nuevo.html"` por `href="/"` ?

Comment: sí lo he probado, da falla igual